# os.system() when used with "strings" command in Ubuntu not working

Tags: python, linux, string, ubuntu, os.system

Consider this command

```
strings --radix=d --encoding={b,l} abc.exe >> xyz.txt
```

When I run this on the Ubuntu terminal it works without any problems.
However when I use it through a python code:

```
import os
os.system("strings --radix=d --encoding={b,l} abc.exe >> xyz.txt")
```

Its not working.
If I remove the "encoding" then it works fine in both cases.
However, I need to get Unicode strings so that part is necessary.
Anyone have any solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ubuntu uses dash by default as /bin/sh, and bash for login shells.

So in your terminal `--encoding={b,l}` is propably expanded by bash to `--encoding=b --encoding=l`, while dash (probably called by os.system as /bin/sh) does no such expansion and it remains `--encoding={b,l}`

The easiest way is to explicitly expand the encoding parameter and don't leave that to the shell, then it will work with any shell.

And you should use the `subprocess` module instead of `os.system()`. Just be aware that when using the `shell=True` argument, it will also call the default `/bin/sh`, which isn't guaranteed to be bash.

Comment: Explicitly expanding as --encoding=l worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `shell=True`, you can pass a list of args and write the `stdout` to a file:

```
from subprocess import check_call
with open('xyz.txt',"a") as out:
    check_call(['strings', '--radix=d', '--encoding={b,l}', 'abc.exe'],stdout=out)
```

A good explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess) of what `shell=True` does

Answer (score 0):

os.system is outdated, use subprocess instead. u also should use `shell=True` to have sh like behaviour:

```
import subprocess

cmd = "strings --radix=d --encoding={b,l} abc.exe >> xyz.txt"
subprocess.check_call(cmd, shell=True)
```

It also throws exception in case of call failure!

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: But without `shell=True` the redirection will not work!

Comment: @rodrigo, it does if you use a list of args and redirect stdout as in my answer